# If 200 records are loaded, how many times will a trigger, PB and a WF be called?

Tags: trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow

If I am loading 200 records, how many times will a PB and a WF be called?
I am aware that triggers execute in chunks of 200, so it will be called only once. Not sure about the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WF and PB are also called "just once." They are all evaluated and the actions queued, then the actions are applied, and then any field updates can cause a second round of execution of the WF and PB (up to five times total). Do be aware, though, that if any field updates occur during those steps, the triggers will execute a second time.